# Truth table for Boolean formula

Tags: calculus

Write a truth table for the Boolean formula (X → Y )AND NOT Y . Include the intermediate calculations
of (X  →Y ) and NOT Y as in the incomplete example below:

X Y (X → Y ) NOT Y (X →Y ) ^ NOTY

tt......"T"......."F"......."F"

t f....."F"......."T"......."F"

f t....."T"......."F"......."T"

f f....."T"......."T"......."T"

Look at the lines of the truth table in which the outcome is true". What do you notice about
the values of X on those lines? "Therefore not x EG x is not true by contradiction"

Now suppose I tell you that:
_ if it is raining when I get up in the morning, I pack my raincoat;
_ I did not pack my raincoat today.
What can you conclude about the weather when I got up today? "It was not raining"

My answer attempt so far are in quotes above.

…am I on the right track?

Regards
j

Comment: My answer so far are in double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

You made one mistake; I’ve corrected it in red below.

$$\begin{array}{cc}
X&Y&X\to Y&\neg Y&(X\to Y)\land\neg Y\\ \hline
T&T&T&F&F\\
T&F&F&T&F\\
F&T&T&F&\color{red}F\\
F&F&T&T&T
\end{array}$$

Your conclusion that if $(X\to Y)\land\neg Y$ is true, then $X$ must be false still holds, and in fact you can also conclude that $Y$ must be false: $(X\to Y)\land\neg Y$ is logically equivalent to $\neg X\land\neg Y$. And because your conclusion that $X$ must be false is correct, your answer to the final part of the question is also correct.